# Printing at Dot Matrix printer from chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I made a A4 size pdf invoice using php and when I print this at dot matrix from chrome then page shrink. But when I print that pdf by downloading and opening through any pdf reader then it print in actual size. Again I tested by opening he downloaded pdf file in chrome then print, but problem is still not resolved. Is it problem of chrome browser or dot matrix printer. I am using TVS dot matrix printer.

Comment: check the chrome print settings

Answer (score 1):

this prolem is common on chrome browser, u can use mozilla instead.

chrome converts the document as image and send to printer.
dot matrix is not good on printing images and thats what happening to u.

Comment: or u can use the socket printing tool which need to be installed on the client machine and the javaschript can communicate to the tool with  socket and can get printed raw format also